# отчет allure от нескольких тестов в один

Tags: pytest, allure

есть следующая ситуация: происходит несколько раз запуск определенных тестов разными командами pytest

```
pytest -sv test_directory1/test1.py --alluredir=directory1
pytest -sv test_directory2/test2.py --alluredir=directory2
                      .....
pytest -sv test_directoryN/testN.py --alluredir=directoryN
```

Возможно ли сделать один отчет allure для из нескольких alluredir? Честно сказать, не удается нагуглить, да и в allure я не шибко силен

Answer (score 0):

как оказалось, особой необходимости в этом нету, т.к. allure serve ${directory} автоматически генерирует отчет из всех содержащихся xml-файлов в этой директории